# What is wrong with this repetition, after the first input an the answer, the program didn't ask for another input and the programs end

Tags: c

Program_to_calculate_area_of_shape_where_P(rectangle)_S(triangle)_T(trapezoid)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int base;
    int height;
    int side;
    int up;
    int down;
    int output;
    int i;
    char type[2];

    type[2] = getche();
    
    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        if(type[i] == 'P')
        {
            scanf("%d", &side);
            getchar();
            
            output = side*side;
        
            printf("%d\n", output);
        }
        else if(type[i] == 'S')
        {
            scanf("%d %d", &base, &height);
            getchar();
            
            output = 0.5*base*height;
        
            printf("%d\n", output);
        }
        else if(type[i] == 'T')
        {
            scanf("%d %d %d", &up, &down, &height);
            getchar();
            
            output = height*(up+down)/2;
        
            printf("%d\n", output);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want the program ask more than 1 user input and stop asking for input if I input '0', the answer of the input include '0' at the end.

[This is the example of input and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTDOA.png)

Comment: The [tag:challenge-response] tag is for questions about the cryptography concept, so I removed it from this question.

Comment: @NateEldredge i'm new to the community, i'm sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1):

why are you using array of size 2 for single char input

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int base;
    int height;
    int side;
    int up;
    int down;
    int output;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        char type = getchar();//This should be inside for loop not outside
        if (type == 'P')
        {
            scanf("%d", &side);

            output = side * side;

            printf("%d\n", output);
        }
        else if (type == 'S')
        {
            scanf("%d %d", &base, &height);

            output = 0.5 * base * height;

            printf("%d\n", output);
        }
        else if (type == 'T')
        {
            scanf("%d %d %d", &up, &down, &height);

            output = height * (up + down) / 2;

            printf("%d\n", output);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm super new to programming and my teacher said that if you input (example: Hello) then it's 6 size of H, e, l, l, o, and \n. So i put array size of 2 for that.

Comment: That's the case with array of char(or string) but not for the single character